# jQuery/PHP - Resize an image with direct proportion

Tags: php, jquery

Hi
Suppose I have several image with different width and height, I want all of them to fit in the img tag with 200 width and 200 height and direct proportion(image won't be distortion).

How can I do it in PHP or Jquery?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var max = 200;
$('img').each(function ()
{
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.height() > $this.width())
    {
        $this.height(max);
    }
    else
    {
        $this.width(max);
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/qtVkT/

Comment: @Charles - you can't size a 500x800 image to 200x200 without having distortion!  (unless you want to crop it)

Comment: Can I fill some "white border" to the image so that the image won't be distortion?

Comment: Yes, just put it in a div that's 200x200 exactly.

Answer (score 1):

This will constrain all images with class 'image' to be <= 200x200px

If you want it to be in a perfect 200x200 box, wrap it in a 200x200px div

```
$('.image').each(function(){
   var $this = $(this);
   $this[$this.width() > $this.height() ? 'width' : 'height'](200);
});
```

Comment: @Matt - Sorry, didn't see your answer, it's identical

Answer (score 0):

From [this tutorial](http://icant.co.uk/articles/phpthumbnails/):

- We assume the thumbnail should be 100 pixels, either wide or high.
- We load the original image, and check its dimensions.
- If the picture is higher than wide, we set the height of the thumb to 100 pixels.
- The width of the thumbnail is the original width multiplied with 100 pixels divided by its height.
- Thumbnail height = original width * (100 / original height)
- This way we preserve the original aspect ratio.
- If the original picture is wider than high, we do the same to the height of the thumbnail.
- If they are the same, we simply create a 100x100 pixels image.

IMO resizing images with jQuery is a bad practice, i advise you shouldn't do that if you can use GD library.